Which was the first cipher that used the Maximum distance separable (MDS) matrix?
MDS matrices are used in the diffusion layer of block ciphers. I am interested in knowing who was the first researcher(s) who used an MDS matrix in their cipher. Thanks in advance.

Their use is extremely connected to the wide-trail strategy introduced by Daemen and Rijmen (https://cs.ru.nl/~joan/papers/JDA_VRI_Wide_2001.pdf).
Some mixing equivalent to a MDS matrix was introduced on the 3-Way block cipher by Daemen in 1994  and their appear on 2 AES predecessors Shark and Square.
Some useful references are chapter 11 of the book The design of Rijndael and chapter 1 of this book
